how to write a library file
I'm trying to learn synthesizing with yosys.Im working with verilog now.
I know we need a library file for it, and I have written a .v file for it. how do I convert this into a .lib file? In other words, how do I write a library for my synthesis?
I've written a .v file, but I don't know how to convert it into a .lib.
this is a simple part of it:
module NOR(A, B, Y);
input A, B;
output Y;
assign #5 Y = ~(A | B);
endmodule

module DFF(C, D, Q);
input C, D;
output reg Q;
always @(posedge C)
    Q <= D;
endmodule

module DFF_PP0 (D, C, R, Q);
input D, C, R;
output reg Q;
always @(posedge C or posedge R) begin
    if (R == 1)
        Q <= 0;
    else
        Q <= D;
end
endmodule

module DFF_PP1 (D, C, R, Q);
input D, C, R;
output reg Q;
always @(posedge C or posedge R) begin
    if (R == 1)
        Q <= 1;
    else
        Q <= D;
end
endmodule


There is no concept of library in verilog. Verilog header files allow you to store commonly used modules and components that you can use in your Verilog files. While Verilog itself doesn't have a formal library format like some other hardware description languages (HDLs) do, such as VHDL with its .lib files, Verilog designs can still be organized into libraries in a similar way, typically through file organization and directory structures.

so you mean I can't write a .lib with verilog? But I have certainly seen .lib files with verilog structures as I've written above.
